# Python & BeautifulSoup 4/Selenium - Unable to get data from kicksusa.com?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from kicksusa.com and I'm running into some issues.

When I try a basic BS4 method, like this (the imports are copy/pasted from the main program which uses all of these):

```
import requests
import csv
import io
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data1 = requests.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/')
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1.text, 'html.parser')

button = soup1.find('span', attrs={'class': 'shop-btn'}).text.strip()
print(button)
```

the result is "None", which tells me the data is hidden via JS. So, I tried to use Selenium, like so:

```
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/') 
url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='shop-btn']").text
print(url)
driver.close()
```

I get "Unable to find element".

Does anybody know how this site can be scraped using BS4 or Selenium? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your selenium code is correct and works well with Firefox driver. `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='shop-btn']").text)` outputs 'Shop Puma' using Firefox driver. Maybe it's a problem with headless chrome? Also you should try timeout between `get` and `find_element_by_xpath`.

Comment: what data are you actually after? Just the text like shop puma etc? Or do you intend to click on the buttons?

Comment: @nmb.ten - That's strange, this same code works with Chrome driver on another URL/website. I will try to add timeout, thank you for your input.

Comment: @QHarr - I am only trying to get text, the above snippet is just an example from when I tried to get any data at all(I am after a.hrefs of divs with class "item" on this [exact URL](https://www.kicksusa.com/mens-shoes.html) - and from there I will feed the hrefs to a loop that opens them and takes the brand and model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you detected as a bot and get response as below:

```
<html style="height:100%">
    <head>
        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px;height:100%">
    <iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=20&xinfo=5-36224256-0%200NNN%20RT%281552245394179%20277%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%200%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B15%2811%2c110765%2c0%29%20U2&incident_id=314001710050302156-195663432827669173&edet=15&cinfo=0b000000"
            frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula
        incident ID: 314001710050302156-195663432827669173
    </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Requests and  BeautifulSoup

If you want use `requests` and `bs`, copy from browser developer tools `visid_incap_` and `incap_ses_` cookies from request header to `www.kicksusa.com` and use them in your `request`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.kicksusa.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
    'Cookie': 'visid_incap_...=put here your visid_incap_ value; incap_ses_...=put here your incap_ses_ value',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/', headers=headers)

page = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

shop_buttons = page.select("span.shop-btn")
for button in shop_buttons:
    print(button.text)

print("the end")
```

---

### Selenium

And when you run Selenium *sometimes* you get same response:
[image]

Reload page works for me. Try code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/')

if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[name=ROBOTS]")) > 0:
    driver.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/')

shop_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.shop-btn")
for button in shop_buttons:
    print(button.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response. The BS4 method is still giving me "None" as a result (I'm positive I correctly put the visid_incap and incap_ses values). The Selenium method seems to be working very well even after fiddling with it to get the exact data I'm after. If you could please explain how to find the response in the first part of your reply, I would be very grateful, as I will be able to troubleshoot similar situations myself in the future.

Comment: @kamen1111 I got init_incap value in chrome private window. Value look like: init_incap_40678=....

Comment: @kamen1111 also I don’t know if they have timeout. You can also open page with Selenium just to get init values from cache and then use requests for further parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.It should return you the text of the button.Hope this help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/')
url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.shop-btn")
print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", url))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this still returns `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.shop-btn"}`

Comment: Strange.I can see the button text.did you copy exactly what I written

Comment: I made sure I copied the exact code, I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

For the links you want as they repeat you can limit to the first of each pair with the following css selector

```
#products-grid .item [href]:first-child
```

i.e.

```
.find_elements_by_css_selector("#products-grid .item [href]:first-child")
```

Comment: Thanks - this will definitely be useful for another program I need to write, but I do believe there's some bot detection at play in this case. `requests.get` in `data1 = requests.get('https://www.kicksusa.com/mens-shoes.htm')` is not pulling the data it is supposed to be pulling.